# Optional Default Parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function with default parameters in swift.

```
func test(string: String = "", middleString: String = "", endString: String = "") -> Void {
  // do stuff
}
```

I want to pass in variables that will be optional strings.

```
let string: String? 
let middleString: String?
let endString: String?
```

How do I make it so that if the parameters are nil, use the default parameters. 
If not, then use the values within the optionals.

`test(string, middleString: middleString, endString: endString)`

Comment: Your function would have to check for nil and then apply the default values if it is nil. The `??` operator makes it easy to do that as in `let s:String = string ?? ""`

Comment: Also, default parameters are for allowing you to leave parameters out from the method call, not anything else

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You'll have to use Optional strings `String?` as your argument type, with default values of `nil`. Then, when you call your function, you can supply a string or leave that argument out.

```
func test(string: String? = nil, middleString: String? = nil, endString: String? = nil) -> Void {
    let s = string ?? ""
    let mS = middleString ?? ""
    let eS = endString ?? ""
    // do stuff with s, mS, and eS, which are all guaranteed to be Strings
}
```

Inside your function, you'll have to check each argument for `nil` and replace with a default value there. Using the `??` operator makes this easy.

You can then call your function by supplying all arguments, no arguments, or only the ones you want to include:

```
test(string: "foo", middleString: "bar", endString: "baz")
test()
test(string: "hello", endString: "world")
```

Comment: The OP can delete the `-> Void` in the function declaration (and the `= nil`s if the implementation doesn't require parameter defaults).

Comment: @AaronBrager Agreed with the `-> Void`, but I like to mirror the OP's code when it's not detrimental. Regarding the default params, I read it as one of the main parts of his question.

Comment: Makes sense. FWIW, I didn't mean that as a correction, I was just expanding on your answer.

Comment: @AaronBrager Don't worry! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 test(string: string ?? "", middleString: middleString ?? "", endString: endString ?? "")
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but only if you want to supply default arguments at _call time_, instead of the function having built-in defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Don't interpret this optional parameters as `?`, this is different approach.

Totally optional parameters, i.e Don't even use while calling method.

```
func doAddition(value1Name value1:Int = 0, value2Name value2:Int = 0, value3Name value3:Int = 0){
    print(value1+value2+value3)
}
```

Now all parameters are optional to add. call how you like,

```
doAddition(value1Name: 1)
doAddition(value1Name: 1, value2Name: 2)
doAddition(value3Name: 3)
```