# How does type inference work with optionals?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a func like this:

```
func click(sender:UIButton?) {
//some code
}
```

and  I want to call that func both like this:

```
 - click() // ERROR: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
 - click(btn) // works
 - click(nil) // works
```

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301844/optional-default-parameter-in-swift) question but I am still confused isn't an optional by default a `nil` isn't that what the whole idea of optionals is about? Why can't I just do `click()` ?

FYI I do know that I can change the method signature to `func click(sender:UIButton? = nil)` and then `click()` would work but that somehow seems redundant and is like re-saying something  that is *already* known to be the default

Comment: you need to manually set the nil `func click(sender:UIButton? = nil)`  parameters will not give you default values

Comment: click() is a different function than click(sender: UIButton?), Declare a new function with just click() and you'll see.

Comment: The question you reference is about default values, not optionals. If your function signature was `func click(sender:UIButton? = nil)` it would work as you expect.

Comment: The signature of the function differs. "click" vs "click : UIButton?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking about two different things:

- An optional **type** which is `nil by default`

  ```
  var button : UIButton?
  ```
- An optional **function parameter** by passing a default `nil` value

  ```
  func click(sender:UIButton? = nil)
  ```

Comment: ohhhhk. Thanks for the simple outline. So the only way to be able to not send parameters is by setting a default value?

Comment: I was just reading about initializers and realized that my confusion was stemming from confusing a normal function call with **initializers**, where if you have an *optional* property, you are allowed to not include it in the initializer. :D